# How to find out which process triggered join_any in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, process

I have three tasks running in parallel and the fork joins when one of them gets completed. I would like to know which one was completed first and caused the fork to join. Is there a way to know it?

```
fork
   task1();
   task2();
   task3();
join_any;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good interactive debugging tool will let you set a breakpoint on the `join_any` or the statement that follows it. Then you will be able see which processes are still running.

If you are looking for a programmatic way, one of many I can think of is pushing a unique ID on a queue and then popping the first one off the queue after the `join_any` will tell you which one finished first.

```
int Qid[$];
fork 
  begin task1(); Qid.push_back(1); end
  begin task2(); Qid.push_back(2); end
  begin task3(); Qid.push_back(3); end
join_any
$display("task%0d finished first", Qid.pop_front() );
```